# Question about Tight Frames.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is vector space of dimension $n$. Prove or disprove the following statement:

Is there a Tight Frame of dimension $m>n$ such that if you consider any subset of $n$ elements then is still a Frame?

**I think:** That the answer is Yes! But i can prove it. 
I don't know how to approach it. Please any help with this problem?

Comment: PD: The new subsets not necessarily have to be Tight Frames, is sufficient to be a frame.